# Missing piece of pgfplot of function

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am attempting to graph the function *y = √{x<sup>2</sup> - 0.5}*, seen here:

[image: graph of above function]

The code I have is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3, xmax=3,
        ymin=-3, ymax=3,
        axis lines = center,
        xtick={-3,-2.5,...,2.5,3},
        ytick={-3,-2.5,...,2.5,3},
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex}
        ]

        \addplot [mark=none, unbounded coords=jump] {sqrt(x^2 - 0.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which almost works, but produces this weird discontinuity:

[image: output of code above]

I added the `unbounded coords=jump` part myself as otherwise there was just a horizontal line connecting those two bottom endpoints. Why does this not continue to display the output of the function below y = ~0.4? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please help us to help you. It is not fun to type from scratch mising part of your code snipped that it will become small, complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with ``end{document}`, which can we than compile and see, where is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square root has real values in the domain`]-∞,-√.5] U [√.5,∞[`, so you need to plot the two sub-domains separately. Taking the absolute `abs()` under the root will guarantee the output being real.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3, xmax=3,
        ymin=-3, ymax=3,
        axis lines = center,
        xtick={-3,-2.5,...,2.5,3},
        ytick={-3,-2.5,...,2.5,3},
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex}
        ]
        \addplot [samples=300,domain=sqrt(.5):3]{sqrt(abs(x^2 - 0.5))};
        \addplot [samples=300,domain=-3:-sqrt(.5)]{sqrt(abs(x^2 - 0.5))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You have problem with number of samples. Around *y =* 0 you actually need infinity many ... try, if the following solution is close to what you like to have:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3, xmax=3,
        ymin=-3, ymax=3,
        axis lines = center,
        xtick={-3,-2.5,...,3},
        ytick={-3,-2.5,...,3},
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex}
        mark=none, unbounded coords=jump,
        ]
        \addplot [blue, very thick,
                  samples=500, domain=-1:1] {sqrt(x^2 - 0.5)};
        \addplot [blue, very thick,, smooth,
                  samples=10, domain=-3:3] {sqrt(x^2 - 0.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```